# Save context this

Tags: javascript, this, prototype

I found some interesting problem. Task is to make wrapper to all child-functions, that will delay implementation.

```
function someFunc() {
  console.log(this.someProp);
}

var obj1 = {
  someProp: 1,
  method1: someFunc,
};

var obj2 = {
  someProp: 2,
  method2: someFunc,
};
Function.prototype.defer = function(ms) {
  let self = this;
  setTimeout(self, ms) //<<-- lose context(obj1, obj2)
};
obj1.method1(); // 1
obj2.method2(); // 2
obj1.method1.defer(1000); // 1 after 1 sec, now is undefined
obj2.method2.defer(1000); // 2 after 1 sec, now is undefined
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try preserving the execution context using the  `bind`. `bind()` allows set which specific object will be bound to `this` when a function or method is invoked.

```js
function someFunc() {
  console.log(this.someProp);
}

var obj1 = {
  someProp: 1,
  method1: someFunc,
};

var obj2 = {
  someProp: 2,
  method2: someFunc,
};
Function.prototype.defer = function(ms) {
  setTimeout(this, ms) //<<-- lose context(obj1, obj2)
};
obj1.method1(); // 1
obj2.method2(); // 2
obj1.method1.bind(obj1).defer(1000); // 1 after 1 sec, now is undefined
obj2.method2.bind(obj2).defer(1000); // 2 after 1 sec, now is undefined
```

Comment: Thx, it works, but is there any decision to solve without adding context by bind, because we show context by (obj1.method1...)?

Answer (score 0):

The direct calls to 'obj.method' work because when a function is called as a method of an object, this is set to the object the method is called on.

The defer function isn't called as a method of the object, it is called as a method of Function which is where it gets its this from

Least changes 'fix' to your code is:

```
function someFunc() {
  console.log(this.someProp);
}

var obj1 = {
  someProp: 1,
  method1: someFunc
};

var obj2 = {
  someProp: 2,
  method2: someFunc
};
Object.prototype.defer = function(func, ms) {
  typeof this[func] === 'function' && setTimeout(this[func].bind(this), ms) //<<-- lose context(obj1, obj2)
};
obj1.method1(); // 1
obj2.method2(); // 2
obj1.defer('method1', 1000); // 1 after 1 sec
obj2.defer('method2', 1000); // 2 after 1 sec
```

Depending on your real use case there are probably better ways to do this than adding methods to built in types. For example, making obj1, obj2 be instances of new classes that you declare that extend a base class in your code where you provide common methods like your defer() function.